# Electric meter inaccessible

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property

My landlord has installed the electric meter of my flat, in a fast-food / deli building next to my building. He owns both buildings. I can't get access to the electricity meter when I want to (either because the deli is closed or because I have to negotiate to get access in the deli's "backroom").

The electricity company can re-install the meter somewhere that is accessible to me, but the landlord won't allow me to.

Is there a law that says "If you are the bill-payer you must have unrestricted access to the electricity meter"?

country: United Kingdom
area: London

Comment: Are you the named bill payer with the utility company, or is included in the rent and the landlord is named?

Comment: I am the named bill payer. The rent is not included in the rent.

Comment: The landlord may not allow you to move the meter, because he doesn't own the meter: the meters are property of the power company.

Comment: I have already contacted the power company. They can and are willing to move the meter. But when I made the landlord aware he told me he doesn't allow me to move them and that the meter should stay where it is. Hence why I am in this forum.

Comment: Related, and possible duplicate - https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58185/can-a-tenant-force-their-building-management-to-let-the-tenant-access-their-apar

Answer (score -2):

### You do not have a right to unlimited access

You do have a right to reasonable access during business hours.

Comment: Maybe add a source or some more background?